# Como chamar uma função carregando uma string no Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Sou novo no Django e estou testando,
No caso tenho meu templete posts.html e queria carregar todos os posts de forma resumida na pagina, porém um lado carregaria os post com id par e outro lado com id impar.

Fiz uma função na views.py e queria carregar todos os posts no posts.html.

```
def posted(request):
    posts = Album.objects.all()
    for post in posts:
        if post % 2 == 0:
            return render(request, """<div class="container marketing  ">
<div class="row mb-2 " >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">{{ post.title }}</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.created_at|date:'d, M Y'}}</div>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ post.summary|safe }}</p>
          <a href="/post/{{ post.pk }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{{post.image.url}}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>""",)
        return render(request, """<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Design</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Post title</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 11</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{% static "images/pexels-pixabay-159358.jpg"%}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os templates do django suportam todas as operações que você está fazendo dentro da view. Faça algo do tipo:

```
return render(request "posts.html", {"posts": Album.objects.all()}
```

Dentro do template você consegue iterar e fazer condições sobre os `posts`. Cheque a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/).